# Unable to force clean/remove file from vscode using git

Tags: git, visual-studio-code

I'm trying to use WSL2 to deploy my code, however I have this bunch of my files in my master branch that I simply cannot get rid of.

I've tried stashing and git cleaning them but to no avail. Can someone help me out?

Thanks!

[image]

This is what is shown in the terminal when I enter git status:
[image]

Please advice on how to remove them for good!

Comment: check the diff for said files, it probably is a line ending issue (common on Windows systems)

Comment: This is almost certainly a line-ending issue. Either the files *in the repository* (as committed) have LF-only line endings but your checkout has them with CRLF endings (incorrectly), *or* the files *in the repository* have CRLF line endings (incorrectly) and your checkout has them with LF-only line endings (correctly). Which of these is the case will be shown by `git ls-files --eol`, so run that.

Answer (score -1):

Are these untracked files in your local? If so, you can do the below.

1. Review what is to be deleted. Don’t actually remove anything, but just preview.

`git clean -n` or `git clean --dry-run`

2. Remove untracked directories along with untracked files. If an untracked directory is managed by a different Git repository, it is not removed.

`git clean -fd`

3. You can then check if your files are removed with `git status`.

Comment: Hi Arjun! Thanks for the prompt reply, I've zapped them manually from the file explorer instead